# My shadows using "blender render" are noisy?

Tags: rendering, noise-reduction

Whenever I make a render in Blender, all my shadows are messed up. They aren't just black, they're black but have a lot of noise. I don't know how to explain it better, so I'll post a render where you can see it. 
I added a few red boxes at the parts where it's really annoying, but I also want the other parts to be fixed. 
Thank you so much to the person who can fix this for me! I'm a complete beginner, so I  have no idea how to fix it. Thanks! :)

Regards and thanks in advance,
Jonas
[image: Here is an example from the image.]

Comment: what is your lighting setup? Strong point lights will create crisper shadows. Are unnaturally sharp shadows your goal?

Comment: Ah, thanks! I tried fixing it, however, I'm using cycles now. ;)